# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'ffprobe'

Tags: android, python-3.x, chaquopy

I want to read an audio file with `.mp3` format using `Pydub`in `android chaquopy`. Although, I installed **ffprobe** and **ffmpeg** in my `build.gradle` file, it has an exception with finding **ffprobe** and get permission to it.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
song = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file_path)
```

I checked the internet that there were some same issues. They use **path** of this libraries directly in python code like this :

```
AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
```

Actually, I don't know how can i find these libraries path in my android project.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` package on PyPI doesn't actually contain the ffmpeg program. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/143), Chaquopy doesn't currently provide an ffmpeg build. However, if you can obtain an Android ffmpeg build from elsewhere, you may be able to use it as an external command.